# Preg_Match_All : Compilation failed

Tags: php

I have migrated a site to a new server, I have made sure the PHP version is the same (5.3) as well as the extensions.

I have one issue with preg_match_all. The error I get is:

> preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]:
>   Compilation failed: (?R or (?[+-]digits must be followed by ) at
>   offset 22

This line is:

```
if (preg_match_all('/([^{]++)({([^{}]++|(?R2))*})/', $code, $items, PREG_SET_ORDER)) { // split declarations
```

It is a random plugin with no support, but just wondered if it was actually missing a ).

For some reason, this code works on the original server still.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put a sample of string you are trying to run the function on it.

However, the error is because '?' is an operator in regex. you should escape it. by backslash

```
if (preg_match_all('/([^{]++)({([^{}]++|(\?R2))*})/', $code, $items, PREG_SET_ORDER)) { // split declarations
```